# Normed space and Subspace

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space with norm and $Y$ subspace with non empty interior ($Y^\circ\neq\varnothing$), then $X=Y$.

I'm trying to use the theorem that says: if $X,Y$ normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ bounded linear operator which is "1-1" then $T$ is surjective, isometry and $T^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if $T(\overline{B_X(0,1)})=\overline{B_Y(0,1)}$.

Let $id:Y\to X$ the identity. This is "1-1", linear and continuous thus bounded. I need to prove now that $T(\overline{B_Y(0,1)})=\overline{B_X(0,1)}$ so I'll get $id(Y)=X$ and $id(Y)=Y$ so $X=Y$. Because $Y^\circ\neq\varnothing$ and $0\in Y$ there is $ε>0$ with $B_Y(0,ε)\subset Y^\circ$ then $\frac{1}{ε}B_Y(0,1)\subset Y^\circ\subset Y$ so $B_Y(0,1)\subset Y$ and $T(\overline{B_Y(0,1)})=\overline{B_X(0,1)}$.

Is that right???

Answer (score 0):

As Y as non-empty interior, it contains an open ball of center x and radius r, as Y is a subspace, it contains by translation and homothety the unit open ball, and again by homothety, it contains whole X.